# What is this factor group isomorphic to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $F$ denote the additive group of all functions mapping $\mathbf{R}$ into $\mathbf{R}$, where $\mathbf{R}$ denotes the set of real numbers. Let $K$ be the subgroup of $F$ consisting of the constant functions. Then to which subgroup of $F$ is the factor group $F/K$ isomorphic?

Here's my work:

For any real number $a$, the map $\phi_a \colon F \to F$ defined by $$ \phi_a(f) := f - f(a) $$ for all $f$ in $F$ is a group homomorphism, because we have $$ \phi_a(f+g) = (f+g) - (f+g)(a) = (f - f(a) ) + ( g - g(a) )  =  \phi_a(f) + \phi_a(g) $$ for any $f$, $g$ in $F$.

Furthermore, $$ \ker(\phi_a) = \{ f \in F \colon \phi_a(f) = \hat{0} \} = \{ f \in F \colon  f - f(a) = \hat{0} \} = \{ f \in F  \colon f(x) = f(a) \forall x \in \mathbf{R} \} = K, $$ where $\hat{0}$ denotes the zero function from $\mathbf{R}$ into $\mathbf{R}$.

So, we can conclude that $F/K$ is isomorphic to $\phi_a[F]$. Now $$ \phi_a[F] = \{ \phi_a(f) \colon f \in F \} = \{ f - f(a) \colon f \in F \} = \{ f \in F \colon f(a) = 0 \}. $$ Is it correct?

Comment: There is not a unique subgroup to which it is isomorphic. In fact, it happens to be isomorphic to $F$ since these are just vectorspaces over $\mathbf{R}$ of the same dimension. And the final set you have written does not make sense.

Comment: Tobias Kildetoft, I actually wanted to write '=', and not '-'. Other than that, I'm afraid, I'm not able to make sense of what you mean. While $F$ is of course a vector space, here we're only discussing group theory. For $a= 3$, say, I wonder if the function $x+1$, which is not $0$ at $x = 3$, can be in the group (rather in any group) to which $F/K$ is isomorphic.

Comment: If two vectorspaces are isomorphic then the underlying abelian groups are also isomorphic. Here $F$ is a vectorspace, and the subgroup you mod out by is a subspace, which means that the quotient is also a vectorspace. The isomorphism then follows since the dimensions agree (you mod out by a $1$-dimensional space).

Comment: Tobias Kildetoft, I'm sorry, but I'm unable to appreciate what you're saying, not at least in the present context. And, please do try to answer the question I've posed in my last comment.

Comment: Your answer correctly identifies a subgroup to which it is isomorphic.

Answer (score 0):

We know by the First Isomorphism Theorem of Groups that a group over the Kernel is isomorphic to the image of the group. But is the image of the group a subgroup of the original group?

Comment: David Lawhorn, is it not? Please go through my original post carefully and do point out any flaw you may find in my reasoning. Please also look at Tobias Kildetoft's comments.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think we had a misunderstanding. I'm merely stating that from your reasoning, this appears to be correct.